# Is there a way to get the difference and intersection of tuples or lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples, intersection, difference

If I have lists:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

c = a * b
```

should give me:

```
c = [4, 5]
```

and

```
c = a - b
```

should give me:

```
c = [1, 2, 3]
```

Is this available for Python or do I have to write it myself?

Would the same work for tuples? I will likely use lists as I will be adding them, but just wondering.

Comment: Do you care about multiplicity and/or order?  If not, you can simply use sets.

Comment: Python's `set` class has built in difference and intersection methods.  The only caveat is losing duplicates if that matters.

Comment: @squiguy: in which case a `Counter` would maintain the counts.

Comment: No I don't. I just want the list/collection and then query if a certain integer is in the group.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the order doesn't matter, you can use [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) for this. It has intersection and difference implemented.

```
>>> a = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> b = set([4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
>>> a.intersection(b)
set([4, 5])
>>> a.difference(b)
set([1, 2, 3])
```

Here is the info of time complexities of these operations: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set. Notice, that the order of subtrahends changes operation complexity.

If element can occur several times (formally it is called [`multiset`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)), you can use [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = Counter([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5])
>>> b = Counter([4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
>>> a - b
Counter({1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 5: 1})
>>> a & b
Counter({4: 2, 5: 1})
```