# Finding the missing elements among two tuples in Python

Tags: python, tuples, difference

I have two tuples `a = (('1',), ('2',), ('3',),)` and `b = (('1',), ('3',),)`. I need to get the result as `(('2',),)` since, 2 is the element that is present in `a` and not in `b`.

I referred this [Find intersection of two lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642763/find-intersection-of-two-lists) and [Is there a way to get the difference and intersection of tuples or lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179519/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-difference-and-intersection-of-tuples-or-lists-in-pyth) for getting an idea, but these are for lists and not for tuples. I am not able to use intersection() for tuples.

Is there a way I can get `a-b` in python tuples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to `set` then you can get the difference, then convert it back to `tuple` using `tuple()` function:

```
a = (('1',), ('2',), ('3',),)
b = (('1',), ('3',),)

result = tuple(set(a) - set(b))
print(result)
```

Running example: https://repl.it/M1FD/1

---

If you want the [Symmetric Difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference), elements in either set but not in the intersection:

```
set(a) ^ set(b)
```

or:

```
set(a).symmetric_difference(set(b))
```

Running example: https://repl.it/M1FD/2

Answer (score 1):

[Sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) are very useful for this.

If you're only looking for elements that are in `a` but not in `b`:

```
set(a) - set(b)
```

If you're looking for elements that are in either one of the tuples, but not the other:

```
set(a) ^ set(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use sets as described in the linked answer:

```
In [1]: a = (('1',), ('2',), ('3',),)
In [2]: b = (('1',), ('3',),)
In [3]: set(a).intersection(set(b))
Out[3]: {('1',), ('3',)}
In [4]: set(a).difference(set(b))
Out[4]: {('2',)}
```